# (NSFW) Making a vulgar joke sound natural in Mandarin (Warning: contains offensive language)

Tags: translation, slang

My friend and I were jokingly conversing (read: google translating) in Mandarin Chinese and I spent 20 minutes on Wiktionary trying to translate

*offensive language:*

> "you suck me good and hard through my jorts"

into Mandarin. I ended up with "您吸我好和強通過我牛仔短褲"

(because I dug myself into a pit by making fun of my friend for only using simplified Chinese) and the only parts I'm even slightly confident in are the use of the polite 'you' and jorts as '牛仔短褲'. I know nothing of Chinese grammar or vulgar terms so I was hoping someone could help me not bastardize this language trying to translate this joke.

Comment: What does "you suck me good and hard through my jorts" mean?

Comment: It refers to oral sex.  It means something like "you perform oral sex good and hard through my jeans shorts".  Here, "hard" implies something like it's able to be felt; it's firm and forceful, and is pleasurable.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the language is offensive.

Comment: That is valid. I probably should of checked if this was against any rules before posting.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it contains inappropriate language.

Comment: I edited out the offensive language in the title and re-opened this post. I believe foul language is still a part of the language. One cannot learn a language without learning the dirty words in it also

Comment: A sentence can be offensive/inappropriate without the foul words, it's the context.

Answer (score 0):

I would translate it as

*offensive language:*

> "you suck me good and hard through my jorts" --> "您隔著我的短褲替我落力吹簫"

doing something 'good and hard' means you do it 'earnestly' which is 落力 in Chinese

*offensive language:*

> the slang for 'performing oral sex' is 吹簫 (play flute) in Chinese